# Ipython change interpreter?

Tags: python, ipython

How does one change Python interpreter used by Ipython? Ipython is great environment for use in Python scripting, with it's powerfull autocomplete and other neat features. However under Archlinux python defaults to python 3. How it is possible to change Ipython to use /usr/bin/python2 as interpreter for Ipython. I don't need pernament solution that would affect other programs, I want to use python2 interpreter on demand: like being able to do one session of Ipython in python2 second one in python3. Is there proper way to do it. 
Ipython website states, that it is able to work with even jython and other version of python, but it seems, that it does not state how to change interpreter on which ipython runs. At least I couldn't find anything. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Usually distrib ship with `ipython` for default system Python `ipython3` for Python 3 and so I suppose `ipython2` for Python2 when ipython default to Python3.

If you want something quick for python2, clone source, cd into it, then.

```
$python2 ipython.py --Usual.options
```

Comment: Thanks indeed that was true: that it has `ipython2`, I missed that because of blind asumption, that ipython has one version only there is different interpreters which can be changed. I think the source solution is pretty handily, so I will have it in mind.